# Deletion-Contraction Recurrence Problem

Tags: graph-theory

Let $P_{k}(G)$ be the Chromatic Polynomial of a Graph G.

(a) Using the deletion-contraction recurrence, show that 
$P_{k}(C_{r})= P_{k}(L_{r}) - P_{k}(C_{r-1})$
where $C_{r}$ is the circuit with $r$ vertices and $L_{r}$ is the path ($L$ for line) consisting of $r$ vertices.

(b) Solve the recurrence in (a) to obtain a formula for $P_{k}(C_{r})$.

I honestly have next to no clue how to even begin this problem. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you point to a more specific place where you are stuck? Do you know the relevant definitions (chromatic polynomial, deletion-contraction)?

Comment: I understand chromatic polynomials however not deletion-contraction. I have a rough idea of it but not a overall understanding which is fairly evident I need for this problem.

Comment: Imagine you have a graph $G$ and you choose a particular edge $e$. Form two new graphs based on this: one by deleting the edge and one by contracting it (that is, merge its two endpoints into a single point). These graphs at called $G - e$ and $G / e$, respectively. The recurrence claims that $P_k(G) = P_k(G - e) - P_k(G / e)$. How might you apply this idea to the cycle graph in your example?

Comment: From what I gather, I am letting the edge $e$ be the last edge from the $r$th vertex which links back to the first vertex. Removing it would yield a path with $r$ vertices. As far as the second one goes, I am not sure how to form that, let alone find its chromatic polynomial.

Comment: Actually looking at it more I can see how the contracting polynomial would be a path of length $r-1$. Not sure how it would be a circuit though.

Comment: You may want to look at some pictorial examples of these operations. Contracting an edge of $C_r$ gives $C_{r-1}$, since we are merging to vertices into one. The resulting vertex has degree two, as before, and we have thereby created a smaller cycle. Deleting an edge, however, leaves all vertices intact, but reduces the degree of each by one, resulting in a path on $r$ vertices.

Comment: I think I figured out part (a). What would be a good approach to part (b)? Maybe try and use a generating function?

Comment: Generating functions are probably overkill. Since the deletion-contraction recurrence leaves you with another cycle on the righthand side, you can apply it again (and again and again...). Perhaps use induction after that if you want to be extra formal.

Comment: How would you apply it over and over?

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks for all the help!